# Selenium XPath Selector for link with no text

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Base on this anchor link with no text inside but different children div's what I am trying to do is click on the element that takes me to another page. Sadly I have not be able to get it. Any advice? my selectors options that I have tried are below

```
<div id="divProducts" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; width:100%;">
 <a class="listProd grayButton roundCorners shadow" tabindex="0" href="#" onclick="ProdOnClick(); $('#divNewApp').load('NewApplication'); return false;">
   <div style="width: 15%; display: inline-block;" aria-label="Life,">
      Life
   </div>
   <div style="width: 30%; display: inline-block;" aria-label="PA Wealth Transfer Trust,">
      PA Form
   </div>
   <div style="width: 35%; display: inline-block; font-size: large;" class="blueText">
      MT Form
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Selenium selectors options used but with no results;

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='divProducts']/a[1]");
By.xpath("//*a[contains(.,'Life')]");
By.xpath("//*[@id='divProducts']/a[contains(.,'MT Form')]");
By.partialLinkText("MT Form");
By.linkText("MT Form");
By.cssSelector("a:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(3)");
By.cssSelector("#divProducts > a:nth-child(1)");
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: As far as I understand I think you want to get the `href` value of the element that can be done by using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#divProducts").get_attribute('href')`.

Comment: Try recording the scenario with Selenium IDE and see what locator gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML cliecking on either of the *link texts* should navigate to the same destination page.

---

### Solution

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Life"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.listProd.grayButton.roundCorners.shadow[onclick^='ProdOnClick'] div[aria-label='Life,']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='listProd grayButton roundCorners shadow' and starts-with(@onclick, 'ProdOnClick')]/div[@aria-label='Life,']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```